# How can i show a rectangle on the map?

Tags: android, google-maps, user-interface

I want to draw a rectangle on the map. The rectangle has a button and a shape and a text.
I can draw a rectangle on the map but when i move my finger on the screen, the size of rectangle changed.Why? I don't know how can i put a button and text and shape on the map. Please help me.

[image]